# html5 video with createjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, createjs

I'm attempting to play a video in canvas with createjs and javascript. I get the video box to show but the video does not play. Im usign the following code in my html page and my game.js file.

Any help would be great.

game.js page

```
        var introVideo = document.getElementById("introVideo");
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(introVideo);
        stage.addChild(bitmap);

        stage.update();
```

htmlpage

```
   <video autoplay id="introVideo" style="display:none">
        <source src="Images/sequencePlayBtn.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must continually update the stage, not just once. The `stage.update()` redraws the stage children and reflect changes, and a video is constantly changing.

Try this to update the stage at a constant rate.

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```